# Why sized trait is required for a builder function to generate Rc<T>?

Tags: rust, traits, smart-pointers, trait-objects

This code works fine ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7bdad61d33a9e48e33558024afedf138)):

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

struct Bar<T> {
    v: Rc<T>,
}

impl<T> Bar<T> where
T: Foo {
    fn new(rhs: Rc<T>) -> Bar<T> {
        Bar{v: rhs}
    }
}

struct Zzz {
}

impl Zzz {
    fn new() -> Zzz {
        Zzz{}
    }
}

impl Foo for Zzz {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Zzz foo");
    }
}

fn make_foo() -> Rc<Foo> {
    Rc::new(Zzz{})
}

fn main() {
    let a = Bar::new(Rc::new(Zzz::new()));
    a.v.as_ref().foo()
}
```

but if I make a wrapper to generate Rc like below, the compiler complains about missing sized trait ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=bf343359ba4c2478200c00cbcf2f544c))

```
fn make_foo() -> Rc<dyn Foo> {
    Rc::new(Zzz::new())
}

fn main() {
    let a = Bar::new(make_foo());
    a.v.as_ref().foo()
}
```

in both cases, Bar::new received parameters with same type Rc, why the rust compiler reacts different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [core::marker::Sized not implemented for Foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446485/coremarkersized-not-implemented-for-foo)

Comment: Applied to this question: `T` has a `Sized` constraint by default, which should be removed when implementing `new(rhs: Rc<T>)`:  `impl<T: ?Sized> Bar<T> where
T: Foo { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all type variables are assumed to be `Sized`. For example, in the definition of the `Bar` struct, there is an implicit `Sized` constraint, like this:

```
struct Bar<T: Sized> {
    v: Rc<T>,
}
```

The object `dyn Foo` *cannot* be `Sized` since each possible implementation of `Foo` could have a different size, so there isn't one size that can be chosen. But you are trying to instantiate a `Bar<dyn Foo>`.

The fix is to opt out of the `Sized` trait for `T`:

```
struct Bar<T: ?Sized> {
    v: Rc<T>,
}
```

And also in the context of the implementations:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Bar<T>
where 
    T: Foo
```

`?Sized` is actually not a constraint, but relaxing the existing `Sized` constraint, so that it is not required.

A consequence of opting out of `Sized` is that none of `Bar`'s methods from that `impl` block can use `T`, except by reference.